# select from the table name values after _ using oracle sql

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Suppose if the table name is ABC_XYZ_123. I want to extract the integer values after _.
The output should be integer values after _.
In the above case, the output should be 123.

I have used the below sql query.

```
select from table_name like 'XXX_%';
```

But I am not getting required output. Can anyone help me with this query.

Thanks

Comment: What is the result if the input is `ABD_323_420`? If that is not possible, make your problem clearer. For example, you may say "All strings will have at least one underscore; and the last substring after the last underscore is entirely digits, that's the substring I need".

Answer (score 0):

Using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with a capture group we can try:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(name, '_(\d+)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: This makes many assumptions - see for example the question I just asked the OP.

Comment: I tried to execute the query. But I am not getting required output

Answer (score 0):

The question is somewhat unclear:

- it looks as if you're looking for **table names** that contain number at the end, while
- query you posted suggests that you're trying to select those numbers from one of table's **columns**

I'll stick to

> Suppose if the table name is ABC_XYZ_123

If that's so, it is the **data dictionary** you'll query. `USER_TABLES` contains that information.

Let's create that table:

```
SQL> create table abc_xyz_123 (id number);

Table created.
```

Query selects numbers at the end of table names, for all my tables that end with numbers.

```
SQL> select table_name,
  2         regexp_substr(table_name, '\d+$') result
  3  from user_tables
  4  where regexp_like(table_name, '\d+$');

TABLE_NAME           RESULT
-------------------- ----------
TABLE1               1
TABLE2               2
restore_point-001    001
ABC_XYZ_123          123        --> here's your table

SQL>
```

Apparently, I have a few of them.